# Image is hidden underneath navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I would like for my image to be displayed directly underneath the navigation bar without the top part of the image being cut off. Is there any way to resolve this? The website needs to be responsive for desktop, tablet and mobile. Apologies for the poor code layout, the navigation does work properly here http://nathan-bayne.co.uk/index1:

```css
/* ------------------------------------------
  START OF RESPONSIVE NAV STYLES
--------------------------------------------- */

 @font-face {
 font-family: "responsivenav";
 src:url("../icons/responsivenav.eot");
 src:url("../icons/responsivenav.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
 url("../icons/responsivenav.ttf") format("truetype"),
 url("../icons/responsivenav.woff") format("woff"),
 url("../icons/responsivenav.svg#responsivenav") format("svg");
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 }

.nav-toggle {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
text-decoration: none;
text-indent: -300px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 60px;
height: 55px;
float: right;
} /* Styles and positions the hamburger menu icon */

.nav-toggle:before {
color: #fff; /* Edit this to change the icon color */
font: normal 28px/55px "responsivenav"; /* Edit font-size (28px) to change 
the icon size */
text-transform: none;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
content: "\2261"; /* Hamburger icon */
text-indent: 0;
/* speak: none; */
width: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}

.nav-toggle.active:before {
font-size: 24px;
content: "\78"; /* Close icon */
} /* Styles the closing icon tag within the hamburger menu */

.header li a {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#cdffff, #cdffff);
  background-position: 0% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 2px;
  transition: background-size .3s;
} /* Sets positioning, adds border line, and removes any text decoration  */

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover,
.header li a:focus {
background-color: #2e8585;
background-size: 100% 2px;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
} /* Sets background colour of nav links when you hover over them */ 

.nav-collapse ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-collapse li {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.js .nav-collapse {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  zoom: 1;
}

.nav-collapse.opened {
  max-height: 9999px;
}

.disable-pointer-events {
  pointer-events: none !important;
}

.nav-toggle {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1044px) {
  .js .nav-collapse {
    position: relative;
  }
  .js .nav-collapse.closed {
    max-height: none;
  }
  .nav-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* ------------------------------------------
  END OF RESPONSIVE NAV STYLES
--------------------------------------------- */


@media only screen and (max-width: 1606px) {

  .logo {
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-top: 7px;
  }

  .centered-image-text {
    top: 34%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #cdffff;
    -webkit-text-stroke: black 2px;
    text-align: center;
  } /* Edits text overlaying image positioning, colour of text and adds stroke */

  .home-section-image {
    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 740px; 
  }
  
  .centered-text1 {
    font-size: 10vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the first line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text2 {
    font-size: 6vw;
    margin-top: -1.5%;
  } /* Edits sizing and margin of the second line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text3 {
    font-size: 5vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the third line of text displayed over the image */

.home-section-image {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.15), 
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.35)
    ),url("../images/test.jpg");
    opacity: .80;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    
    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 840px; 
    
    /* Create the image scrolling effect */
    /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .centered-image-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 36.5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #cdffff;
    -webkit-text-stroke: black 1.5px;
    text-align: center; 
  } /* Edits text overlaying image positioning, colour of text and adds stroke */

  .centered-text1 {
    font-size: 6.2vw;
    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  } /* Edits sizing of the first line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text2 {
    font-size: 4.6vw;
    margin-top: -1.5%;
    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  } /* Edits sizing and margin of the second line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text3 {
    font-size: 4vw;
    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  } /* Edits sizing of the third line of text displayed over the image */
  }

  /*----------------------------------------------
  START OF DISPLAY THE MOVING MESSAGE IN THE BANNER
  ----------------------------------------------*/
  
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {

  .logo {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 2px;
  }

  /*------------------------------
    START OF HOME SECTION
  --------------------------------*/

  .home-section-image {
    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 360px;  /* May change back to original height: 100%; */
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.15), 
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.35)
    ),url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/132037/pexels-photo-132037.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500");
  }

  .centered-image-text {
    top: 20.7%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #cdffff;
    -webkit-text-stroke: black 2px;
    text-align: center;
  } /* Edits text overlaying image positioning, colour of text and adds stroke */

  .centered-text1 {
    font-size: 10vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the first line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text2 {
    font-size: 8.5vw;
    margin-top: -1.5%;
  } /* Edits sizing and margin of the second line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text3 {
    font-size: 8vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the third line of text displayed over the image */
  }
  
  /* ------------------------------------------
  START OF FIXED HEADER
--------------------------------------------- */

header {
  background: #339a9a ;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.logo {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 55px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #cdffff;
  float: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.logo:hover {
  color: #a9fdfd;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mask {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 300ms;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
} /* This adds a black tint over the content when the user clicks the hamburger menu in mobile view */

.android .mask {
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

.js-nav-active .mask {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .mask {
    display: none !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
  }
}


/* ------------------------------------------
  START OF NAVIGATION STYLES
--------------------------------------------- */

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-collapse,
.nav-collapse * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-collapse,
.nav-collapse ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 65em) {
  .nav-collapse {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
  }
}

.nav-collapse li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 65em) {
  .nav-collapse li {
    width: auto;
  }
}

.nav-collapse a {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #339a9a;
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
} /* Edits the nav menu when in hamburger menu view */

.nav-collapse a:active,
.nav-collapse .active a {
  background: #70d1d0;
} /* Sets colour of nav menu section that you are currently looking at */

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .nav-collapse a {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    padding: 1.02em 2em;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 0;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
  } /* Changes positioning and styling of the nav bar titles*/
}

.nav-collapse ul ul a {
  background: #ca3716;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .nav-collapse ul ul a {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* ------------------------------------------
  START OF NAV TOGGLE STYLES
--------------------------------------------- */
```

```html
<header class="header"> 
      <a href="#" class="logo">PositiveTalkwithAJ</a>
      <nav class="nav-collapse">
        <ul>
          <li class="menu-item active"><a href="#home" data-scroll>Home</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#about" data-scroll>About</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#expertise-section" data-scroll>My Expertise</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#contact-section" data-scroll>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section id="home" class="home-section">
      <!--<h1 class="home-section-title"><span>PositiveTalkwithAJ</span></h1>-->

      <div class="home-section-image">
      <div class="centered-image-text">
        <div class="centered-text1">PositiveTalkwithAJ</div>
        <div class="centered-text2">CBT Therapist</div> 
        <div class="centered-text3">Aileen Johnstone</div> 
      </div> 
      </div>

<div class="animated-message-container">
  <div class="animated-message-text">
    <!--<h3>"Your reality is a matter of your perception"</h3>-->
  </div>
<!--<p>Get in touch to discuss session availability.</p>-->
</div>
    </section>
```

If you feel like you need to view my code for the navigation and image, let me know.

Comment: Please do not link to your website. If the issue is fixed or your website changed/removed in general, this question would hold no further value to the community. As such always use a minimal reproduciable code snippet (ctrl + m) to provide a minimal code sample that is showing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe addding this to your css would fix your issue by adding a margin to the top of the page:

```css
section#home {
    margin-top: 63px;
}
```

Comment: it will make it unresponsive as the navbar has not a fixed height. Also there is no need for `section#home` as selector. ID's have to be unique and as such using `#home` as selector is more then sufficient.